# How to use "jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar" in windows 7?

Tags: python-2.7, jython, jython-2.5, jython-2.7

I want to upgrade Jython from "jython2.5.4rc1" to "Jython 2.7-beta3".

I have downloaded following two files from "http://www.jython.org/downloads.html":

```
1. Jython 2.7beta3 - Installer      - jython-installer-2.7-b3.jar
2. Jython 2.7beta3 - Standalone Jar - jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar
```

When I doubleclick on "jython-installer-2.7-b3.jar" file, I am getting "Could n ot find the main class:org.python.util.install.Installation.program will exit" error.

Then I tried by using following command , But I am getting same error:

```
C:\Users\Downloads>java -jar jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/python/util/jython : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.python.util.jython. Program will exit.
```

C:\Users\Downloads>

I tried both Installer and standalone jar files using the above command. Its throws same error.

Could anyone please guide me on How to install this "jython-installer-2.7-b3.jar" file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" means your version of Java is too old.  Running java -jar jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar was successfull with version 1.7 ...

```
d:\work>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```